# How to send data with commands using Ionic Ble

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send a command to a Ble device in order to receive the data corresponding to that function(+I.) but it does not respond with the corresponding data in the subscribe, however when I use the +O command, which is a similar function (delivers the data of the available Wi-Fi) this works. I tried the commands using the Light blue app to make sure they were not the commands and they work correctly.

```
  peripheral: any = {};
  statusMessage: string | undefined;
  wifi: any = {};
  public dataFromDevice: any;
  largo: number | undefined;
  texto='+O.'
  texto2='+I.';
  wifiSelected: string | undefined;
  

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams, 
              private ble: BLE,
              private modal: IonModal,
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              private ngZone: NgZone,
              public bluetooth: BluetoothService,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.bluetooth.getDevices            
    let device = this.bluetooth.devices 
    console.log("esto envia aqui",device.id);
               

    this.setStatus('Connecting to ' + device.name || device.id);

    this.ble.connect(device.id).subscribe(
      peripheral => this.onConnected(peripheral),
      peripheral => this.onDeviceDisconnected(peripheral)
    );

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    
  }
  

  async BleWrite(inputdata: any) {

    // Subscribe for notifications when the resitance changes
    //comando para lectura de red +O.enviar escrito en ascii

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    

    await this.ble
        .write(
            this.peripheral.id,
            BLE_SERVICE,
            BLE_CHARACTERISTIC,
            inputdata
        )
        .then(
            data => {
               debugger;
                   
                
                console.log("esto envia el data",String.fromCharCode.apply(null,[...new Uint8Array(inputdata)]));
                console.log("ahora funciono",data);
                this.subscribe();
                
            },
            err => {
              
                console.log("esta dando error",err);
            }
        );
  //console.log("entrega esto",this.dataFromDevice[0]);      
}

subscribe() {
  console.log("entre al subscribe",this.peripheral.id);
  
   
    this.ble.startNotification(this.peripheral.id, BLE_SERVICE, BLE_CHARACTERISTIC).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              
               console.log("estos son los datos que manda",data);
                this.onValueChange(data);
     
            },
            () =>
                this.showAlert(
                    "Unexpected Error",
                    "Failed to subscribe for changes, please try to re-connect."
                )
         
                
        );
        
        
}

onValueChange(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
  console.log("entre al onvaluechange");
  
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      try {
        if (this.dataFromDevice == undefined) this.dataFromDevice = this.bytesToString(buffer).replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        else {
        this.dataFromDevice += '' + this.bytesToString(buffer).replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        this.dataFromDevice =this.dataFromDevice.toString()
        this.dataFromDevice = JSON.parse(this.dataFromDevice);
        this.dataFromDevice = JSON.parse(this.dataFromDevice);
        this.wifi = this.dataFromDevice;
        console.log("entrega esto",this.wifi[0].ssid) ;
        this.ble.stopNotification(this.peripheral.id, BLE_SERVICE, BLE_CHARACTERISTIC);
      }
    }  catch (e) {
            console.log("dio un error",e);
        }
    });
     
}

bytesToString(buffer: any) {  
  console.log("tostring",String.fromCharCode.apply(
    null,
    [...new Uint8Array(buffer[0])]
  ));
  
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(
    null,
    [...new Uint8Array(buffer[0])]
  )
}

 redSeleccionada(wifiSelected: any){

  this.wifiSelected = wifiSelected;
  console.log("seleccionada",this.wifiSelected);
  
  
 }


  
  

  

  // the connection to the peripheral was successful
  onConnected(peripheral: any) {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.setStatus('');
      this.peripheral = peripheral;
      this.BleWrite(this.codificarUtf8(this.texto));
      
      //this.BleWrite(this.codificarUtf8(this.texto2));
    
    });
    
  }

  async onDeviceDisconnected(peripheral: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'The peripheral unexpectedly disconnected',
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'middle'
    });
    (await toast).present();
  }

  // Disconnect peripheral when leaving the page
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewWillLeave disconnecting Bluetooth');
    this.ble.disconnect(this.peripheral.id).then(
      () => console.log('Disconnected ' + JSON.stringify(this.peripheral)),
      () => console.log('ERROR disconnecting ' + JSON.stringify(this.peripheral))
    )
  }


  async showAlert(title: string, message: string) {
    let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: title,
        message: message,
        buttons: ["OK"]
    });
    (await alert).present();
}

  setStatus(message: string | undefined) {
    console.log(message);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.statusMessage = message;
    });
  }

  codificarUtf8(texto: string ) {
    this.largo = texto?.length;
    var textoCodif = new TextEncoder().encode(texto+"L");  
    textoCodif[this.largo] = 0x0a;
   return textoCodif.buffer;
 }
}
```

I want that when sending the command +i, it sends the device information